# Removing sprites in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

```
-(void) update:(ccTime *)dt{
    for( int i=0; i < [objects count]; i++){
         CCSprite *obj = (CCSprite *) [objects objectAtIndex:i];
         if(obj.position.y <= 40){
            [obj stopAllActions];
            [self removeChild:obj cleanup:YES]; /* ?? */
            [objects removeObjectAtIndex:i];
         }
    }
```

}

**I am expecting this code to remove the sprites but its not working. sprite is still on the screen. what i am doing wrong here , please help. thanks.**

EDIT:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"vase.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"vase.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet z:1 tag:1];
//CCSpriteFrame must be created for each animation frame.
NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame %d.png", i];
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:file];
    [animFrames addObject:frame];
}
//Sprite is positioned and then animated.
CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"frame 1.png"];     
CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:0.20f];
CCRepeat *repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:YES] times:3];


[player runAction:repeat];

player.position = startPostion;
[spriteSheet addChild:player];
```

Comment: as the Sprite "obj" is animated sprite. i am using spritesheet, could it be the problem here ?

Comment: please show the code how you create the sprite

Comment: there i am creating the sprites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ure are removing the sprite from `self`, but the sprite is not a child of `self`. It's a child of `spriteSheet` because you've written:

```
[spriteSheet addChild:player];
```

So you have to remove the sprite from `spriteSheet` instead of self. But it's easier to:

```
[sprite  removeFromParentAndCleanup: YES];
```